# Difference between $this->Html->url and $this->Html->link in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

As of my knowledge these both are used for creating links :

What is the main difference between **$this->Html->url** and **$this->Html->link** in Cakephp?

Is there any performance issues occurs for using these?

What if i want to open link in new tab using "**$this->Html->url**"

What i tried :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->url($item['News']['link'],array('target'=>'_blank', 'escape' => false)); ?>
```

but its not working. open link in same tab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is like asking what the difference between apples and trees are. The other requires the other to exist ;) in this case url() is needed for link() to exist and function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to CakePHP Documentation, the HTML->url takes two arguments, the 2nd one is a boolean while the first is a routing array. Try this:

```
<?php echo 
    $this->Html->url(
             array(
                   'href' => $item['News']['link'],
                   'target' => '_blank',
                   'escape' => false
                   ),
             false     // Second argument, true means prepend the path of my site before the link while false means don't prepend
     ); ?>
```

References:

1. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::url
2. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-routing-array

Comment: Can you paste in the comment what it generates?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `$this->Html->link()` method is for. It takes an array of options as parameters to do this.